# Force specific folder to be added to Photos?

Tags: photos, google-photos, media-scanner

How can I force media-scanner to index a particular folder?

I use an app that takes photos and stores them in a sub-folder of it's own data folder. The data folder has a `.nomedia` file, so the photos sub-folder is ignored by Gallery etc. Is there an opposite of `.nomedia` file?

The data folder has a lot of other files an folders which should be ignored by media-scanner.

The ultimate aim is to have these photos backed up to my Google Photos account.

The target folder is not listed under Google Photos >> Settings >> Backup & Sync >> Device Folders.

I tried creating a symlink from `(...)/sdcard/DCIM/foobaz` to the `(...)/foobaz/data/photos` folder but get a message that the operation is not permitted.

Android 7.0, not rooted. (Samsung S6)

Answer (score 2):

- Delete the `.nomedia` file to force media scanning  ( 
  restart the phone. It is then that media scanner database is re indexed )
  and it should appear in Google photos folder list for sync.
- If you don't want that folder to be scanned by media folder at all, create a new folder in gallery ( use a third party file explorer from Play store , if your built in explorer can't do this ) and copy those photos into this folder manually. Verify, it's showing up in Gallery options to sync
- Obviously, you wouldn't want to manually do this every time you use that app, so automate it. [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) app implement it this way

**Trigger:** Application Launched / Closed → Closed → Select your app

**Action:**  File operation → Select   paths and move / copy options

This ensures that everytime you close your app, pictures are moved / copied into gallery sub folder and available for sync

Comment: I deleted the nomedia file but it doesn't appear in folder list. I tried forcing a re-index by installing and running "SD Scanner" app by Jeremy Erickson but that hasn't changed things. I'll let it sit for a day to see if it just needs more time

Comment: Restarted phone but Photos still doesn't see it. ... Then discovered the nomedia file keeps being recreated. Looks like I have no choice but to copy the files as suggested for option 2.(might run out of room for that)

Comment: Instead of copy, there is a move option also, which will prevent duplication

Comment: You can  experiment with file operation V2 Actions also if  it helps

Comment: Moving isn't an option because the app still needs the photos. For now I manually copied the photos using ES File Explorer, let them back up, then used 'delete from device'